# Is it possible to delete a component which is attached to a page without deleting the page itself?

Tags: core-service, componentpresentation, custom-page

I have a many pages and and many components in the publication.

I want to delete the Component that attach to the page without delete the page itself. I tried but it giving me error that:

> This item in is use

I tried this using Core Service and SDL Tridion GUI but both giving me error.

How  is it possible?

Answer (score 8):

You can't delete the component while it is added as a component presentation to a page.
The solution is simple: you should not delete the page, but you should simply remove the component presentation from the page.
Once that's done, you can delete it (unless the component is still used elsewhere, or if it is published with a dynamic component template)

Comment: Note that you should republish the Page after removing the Component Presentation from it. This is not a requirement for deleting, but if you fail to do that, then you would still have the content of that Component published, while it is deleted on the CM.

Answer (score 5):

As Harald said, it is not needed to delete the page to remove the component. Also, if you remove the component presentation from the page, again **you would not be** able to delete the page and will receive the error "Item is in use". This is because this item although you have removed from the Page but from the Current version only and the older versions of the pages are still using that component. To resolve the issue, you also need to delete the older versions of the page using that component.

To delete a component, following should be checked:

- Check where all the component is in use by using `Where Used` functionality
- If it is used in one or more pages - remove it from there, save the page and further remove all older versions which were using this component
- If it is used as an internal links in one or more component - remove it from there, save the component and remove all older versions of component which were using this component
- Try deleting the component and it should now not give you error - "Item in use"
- If now you get error "Item is published", you need to identify where all the component is published - Unpublish from all target where it is published

I hope it helps

Comment: one small note : in tridion 2013 sp1 (probably also without the service pack), it's no longer needed to delete the component presentation from older versions of the page, so it's not needed to delete from older versions. This was the case in older versions. Off course, if you delete the component, and you want to roll back your page to a previous version, you will get an error

Comment: I agree Harald and thanks for sharing the note. Since the question was not tagged with any specific version so just shared the generic information :)

Comment: Older version links preventing deletion only occur in relation to Schemas, since a Schema change will change the XML structure of items.